# AWS cli lambda get-function returns unexpected result in codebuild

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

In aws codebuild, I'm using a bash script to check if the lambda functions exist, if it exists, I will update the source etc...
But the condition always returns true, or code exit 0.

I run the same code locally, it returns exit code 254 (when there is no lambda function) without issue.

```
 for SUB in $SUBFOLDERS; do
    if aws lambda get-function --function-name $SUB --region $region &>/dev/null; then
      echo "Lambda function $SUB already exists. Update source" 
        ...
    fi
 done
```

or even when tried to print out the exit-code

```
for SUB in $SUBFOLDERS; do
  aws lambda get-function --function-name $SUB --region $region &>/dev/null
  exit_code=$?
  echo "Exit Code: $exit_code"
  if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Lambda function $SUB already exists. Update source" 
    ...
  fi
done
```

exit_code was always 0 and my update function will eventually crash the build process.
Anyone has any idea?